# Remove Last Element In Array, Insert New

Tags: c#

I have a `string[]` with the following values in it:

```
x
y
z
```

I am trying to remove the string z, based on the fact that is the last element in the array, and replace it with w. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Length` to find the last index, and just assign it to replace it:

```
myArray[myArray.Length - 1] = "w";
```

Note the -1 since `Length` is not 0-indexed

Answer (score 0):

Possible. If your array has fix 3 item.

Array starts at 0 index, so `z` is at the 2 index.

```
arr[2] = "w";
```